# Error when trying to run Swift from terminal

Tags: xcode, terminal, swift

After entering

```
~   sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode6-Beta3.app/Contents/Developer
```

and then

```
~   xcrun swift
```

I get an error

```
ImportError: No module named site
Assertion failed: (err == 0), function ~Mutex, file /SourceCache/lldb/lldb-320.4.106.2/source/Host/common/Mutex.cpp, line 246.
Abort trap: 6
```

What am I missing? Several tutorials online give this code, so I'm guessing it must be some sort of setup issue.

Comment: You should probably file a bug report with Apple. After all, Swift and Xcode 6 are both still in beta. Errors are to be expected, and reported.

Comment: I assumed from the number of posts giving the same code that it's working for others.I'd be interested to know whether anyone else gets this.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar error and resolved it by removing the entry to my 3rd-party Python distribution (Enthought Canopy, in my case) from the PATH environment variable.  This was a manual hack in my Terminal session and is good for only that session but it was as simple as this:

```
~ [1]$  swift
ImportError: No module named site
~ [2]$  echo $PATH
/Users/tdiller/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:~/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/universal-darwin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
~ [3]$  PATH=PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:~/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/universal-darwin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
~ [4]$  export PATH
~ [5]$  swift
Welcome to Swift version 1.2. Type :help for assistance.
  1>
```

I'm not sure what in `Canopy-64bit/User/bin/` intereferes with Swift, but removing that item on the path seems to do the trick if you want to use the Swift REPL.  There doesn't seem to be a problem with the EPD-style entry (`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework...`).

Of course, Canopy won't work from this Terminal session, but I'm not sure it's important to have Python REPL and Swift REPL working in the same session.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$ xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode6-Beta3.app/Contents/Developer
```

See this article for more [1. Learn Swift by running Scripts](https://medium.com/swift-programming/1-learn-swift-by-running-scripts-73fdf8507f4b)

Comment: Copying error, thanks. Have corrected the original post.